# Frame displayed on SurfaceView is different from frame received by onPreviewFrame [Android]

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am developing an Android APK with Computer Vision algorithms for video. However, I am having a problem. To display the original frame, I use the component SurfaceView. To display the result frame, I receive the frame in YUV (method onPreviewFrame), convert it to RGB/Bitmap and display it on ImageView.

Currently, I do not anything on the frame received by onPreviewFrame, I just convert it and show it. That is, the frame on the SurfaceView and ImageView should be identical. However, I am finding the frames from SurfaceView and ImageView slightly different.

In this image:

[image]

the SurfaceView frame is on the left and the ImageView frame is on the right. The flame in the right image seems more "yellow-ish" than the flame in the left image.

I have tested this in a Samsung S5 with Android 5.0.2 and a LG G3 with Android 4.4.2. Have any of you guys ever perceived this? Does anyone knows the reason for this difference?

Comment: My guess would be differences in the YUV -> RGB conversion. What code are you using to do the conversion?

Comment: Hello, @fadden . To perform the YUV -> RGB conversion, I use an OpenCV functions:  `Imgproc.cvtColor(YUV, RGB, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12)`.